# How can write (persian)or arabic in bottom table in itext5 android?

Tags: java, android, itext, arabic, persian

[image]

problem in photo

How can I write (persian) in bottom table in itext5 android?

My problem is, in the bottom table the characters are separate.

How to write correct persian in bottom table?

My code is:

```
Phrase p ;
public void createPdf(String dest) throws Exception {

    Document document = new Document();
    PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(dest));
    document.open();
    Font f = FontFactory.getFont(FONT, BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED,12);

    PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(new float[] { 2, 1, 2 });


    table.setRunDirection(PdfWriter.RUN_DIRECTION_RTL);
    table.getDefaultCell().setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
    table.getDefaultCell().setPaddingBottom(10);
    table.addCell(new Phrase(":سن", f));
    table.addCell(new Phrase(":وزن", f));
    table.addCell(new Phrase(":مکان", f));
    table.setHeaderRows(1);
    PdfPCell[] cells = table.getRow(0).getCells();
    for (int j=0;j<cells.length;j++){
        cells[j].setBackgroundColor(BaseColor.GRAY);
    }
    for (int i=1;i<45;i++){

        table.addCell(new Phrase("سن"+i, f));
        table.addCell(new Phrase("وزن"+i, f));
        table.addCell(new Phrase("مکان"+i, f));

    }


    document.add(table);
    p = new Phrase("خبر", f);
       String b="در پی برخی خبرسازی ها و شبهه افکنی ها در خصوص ارسال پیامک بررسی برقراری مجدد یارانه برای گروهی از هموطنان، دبیرخانه شورای اطلاع رسانی دولت ضمن تکذیب موارد مطرح شده تاکید کرد که بررسی و برقراری مجدد یارانه افراد معترض که طبق قانون مشمول دریافت یارانه محسوب می شوند اقدامی متعارف و بر اساس روال ماههای گذشته بوده است";
   // p.add(new Phrase("در پی برخی خبرسازی ها و شبهه افکنی ها در خصوص ارسال پیامک بررسی برقراری مجدد یارانه برای گروهی از هموطنان، دبیرخانه شورای اطلاع رسانی دولت ضمن تکذیب موارد مطرح شده تاکید کرد که بررسی و برقراری مجدد یارانه افراد معترض که طبق قانون مشمول دریافت یارانه محسوب می شوند اقدامی متعارف و بر اساس روال ماههای گذشته بوده است", f));
    String name1 = new String(b.getBytes(), "UTF-8");
    document.add(new Phrase(name1,f));

    ColumnText canvas = new ColumnText(writer.getDirectContent());
    canvas.setSimpleColumn(40, 590, 650, 580);
    canvas.setRunDirection(PdfWriter.RUN_DIRECTION_LTR);
    canvas.addElement(p);


    canvas.go();

    document.close();
}
```

What is problem?

Comment: iText supports RTL only for elements which have `RunDirection` property such as tables, table cells, ColumnText, etc.

Comment: I think that  itext have rtl for paragraph